# create anaconda virtual env from exported yaml file or clone

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ubuntu-18.04, anaconda3

I am running python 3 on a ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.  I have installed python with anaconda.  I have created a virtual env named llm_110623.  I have tried exporting the env to a yaml file so that I can change the name and use it as a base to create a new virtual env llm_022624.  When I try creating the new virtual env llm_022624 I'm getting the error messages below.  I have also tried cloning the llm_110623 env, but when I do that I am able to activate the env but can not install/update packages and it doesn't show up in the list of virtual env.  I'm mentioning both issues because I think they may be related.  It seems like maybe conda is having trouble resolving dependencies or adding env to path.  I've added all the code and errors I've gotten below along with the yaml file.  Can someone please tell me what the issue is and suggest how to solve?

code:

```
# activating  conda virtual env

conda activate llm_110623

# exporting env to yaml

conda env export > llm_022624.yml

# then updated name of env in yaml file and saved



# deactivated current virtual env
conda deactivate

# tried to create env from yaml

conda env create -f llm_022624.yml

error:

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \ (base)


# next tried first to activate conda

conda activate

# then tried to create env again

conda env create -f llm_022624.yml


error:

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - Fatal Python error: Immortal interned string died.

Thread 0x00007fb5a5ffb700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5a67fc700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5a6ffd700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5a77fe700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5a7fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c4ff9700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c57fa700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c5ffb700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c67fc700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c6ffd700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5c77fe700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007fb5c7fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/auxlib/logz.py", line 149 in stringify
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 704 in fetch_repodata_remote_request
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 379 in _load
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 210 in load
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 145 in query
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 133 in <lambda>
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 80 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5ecffd700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5ed7fe700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5edfff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5f8ba1700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 78 in _worker
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5fb461700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 418 in _start_spinning
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fb5fe695740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 430 in result
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598 in result_iterator
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 140 in query_all
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 289 in get_reduced_index
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1059 in _prepare
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 463 in _collect_all_metadata
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88 in decorated
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 300 in solve_final_state
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 196 in solve_for_diff
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 155 in solve_for_transaction
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/installers/conda.py", line 51 in install
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 142 in execute
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 80 in do_call
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082 in __call__
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1374 in conda_exception_handler
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 91 in main
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda-env", line 7 in <module>



# next tried exporting with nobuilds, but basically ran into same cycle

conda env export -f llm_022624_nobuild.yml --no-builds
# change name of env in yaml file

conda env create -f llm_022624_nobuild.yml

error message:

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | (llm_110623)


# I also tried creating a clone of the env

conda create --name llm_022624 --clone llm_110623

# activate cloned env

conda activate llm_022624

# list installed packages

conda list


# error
EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/llm_022624


# it doesn't show up when I run conda env list

# I tried updating one of the packages and I get this error

conda update transformers

error:

DirectoryNotACondaEnvironmentError: The target directory exists, but it is not a conda environment.
Use 'conda create' to convert the directory to a conda environment.
  target directory: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/llm_022624



# yaml file

name: llm_022624
channels:
  - xformers
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - conda-forge/label/cf202003
  - nvidia
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1
  - _openmp_mutex=5.1
  - abseil-cpp=20211102.0
  - aiohttp=3.8.5
  - aiosignal=1.2.0
  - appdirs=1.4.4
  - arrow-cpp=11.0.0
  - asttokens=2.0.5
  - async-timeout=4.0.2
  - attrs=23.1.0
  - aws-c-common=0.6.8
  - aws-c-event-stream=0.1.6
  - aws-checksums=0.1.11
  - aws-sdk-cpp=1.8.185
  - backcall=0.2.0
  - blas=1.0
  - boost-cpp=1.73.0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5
  - brotlipy=0.7.0
  - bzip2=1.0.8
  - c-ares=1.19.0
  - ca-certificates=2023.12.12
  - certifi=2024.2.2
  - cffi=1.15.1
  - chardet=4.0.0
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4
  - click=8.1.7
  - colorama=0.4.6
  - comm=0.1.2
  - cryptography=41.0.2
  - cuda-cudart=11.7.99
  - cuda-cupti=11.7.101
  - cuda-libraries=11.7.1
  - cuda-nvrtc=11.7.99
  - cuda-nvtx=11.7.91
  - cuda-runtime=11.7.1
  - cudatoolkit=10.1.243
  - cudnn=7.6.5
  - datasets=2.12.0
  - debugpy=1.5.1
  - decorator=5.1.1
  - dill=0.3.6
  - einops=0.2.0
  - et_xmlfile=1.1.0
  - executing=0.8.3
  - ffmpeg=4.2.2
  - filelock=3.9.0
  - freetype=2.12.1
  - frozenlist=1.3.3
  - fsspec=2023.9.2
  - gflags=2.2.2
  - giflib=5.2.1
  - glog=0.5.0
  - gmp=6.2.1
  - gmpy2=2.1.2
  - gnutls=3.6.15
  - grpc-cpp=1.48.2
  - huggingface_hub=0.15.1
  - icu=58.2
  - idna=3.4
  - intel-openmp=2023.1.0
  - ipykernel=6.19.2
  - ipython=8.12.0
  - jedi=0.18.1
  - jinja2=3.1.2
  - joblib=1.2.0
  - jpeg=9e
  - jupyter_client=8.1.0
  - jupyter_core=5.3.0
  - krb5=1.20.1
  - lame=3.100
  - lcms2=2.12
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.38
  - lerc=3.0
  - libboost=1.73.0
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9
  - libcublas=11.10.3.66
  - libcufft=10.7.2.124
  - libcufile=1.7.0.149
  - libcurand=10.3.3.53
  - libcurl=8.1.1
  - libcusolver=11.4.0.1
  - libcusparse=11.7.4.91
  - libdeflate=1.17
  - libedit=3.1.20221030
  - libev=4.33
  - libevent=2.1.12
  - libffi=3.4.4
  - libgcc-ng=11.2.0
  - libgfortran-ng=11.2.0
  - libgfortran5=11.2.0
  - libgomp=11.2.0
  - libidn2=2.3.4
  - libnghttp2=1.52.0
  - libnpp=11.7.4.75
  - libnvjpeg=11.8.0.2
  - libopus=1.3.1
  - libpng=1.6.39
  - libprotobuf=3.20.3
  - libsodium=1.0.18
  - libssh2=1.10.0
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0
  - libtasn1=4.19.0
  - libthrift=0.15.0
  - libtiff=4.5.0
  - libunistring=0.9.10
  - libuuid=1.41.5
  - libvpx=1.7.0
  - libwebp=1.2.4
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4
  - lz4-c=1.9.4
  - markupsafe=2.1.1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6
  - mkl=2023.1.0
  - mkl-service=2.4.0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.6
  - mkl_random=1.2.2
  - mpc=1.1.0
  - mpfr=4.0.2
  - mpmath=1.3.0
  - multidict=6.0.2
  - multiprocess=0.70.14
  - ncurses=6.4
  - nettle=3.7.3
  - networkx=2.8.4
  - numexpr=2.8.4
  - numpy=1.25.0
  - numpy-base=1.25.0
  - openh264=2.1.1
  - openpyxl=3.0.10
  - openssl=3.0.13
  - orc=1.7.4
  - packaging=23.0
  - pandas=2.1.1
  - pandas-stubs=1.5.3.230203
  - parso=0.8.3
  - pexpect=4.8.0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5
  - pillow=9.4.0
  - pip=23.2.1
  - platformdirs=2.5.2
  - pooch=1.4.0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.36
  - psutil=5.9.0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2
  - pyarrow=11.0.0
  - pycparser=2.21
  - pygments=2.15.1
  - pyopenssl=23.2.0
  - pysocks=1.7.1
  - python=3.10.12
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2
  - python-tzdata=2023.3
  - python-xxhash=2.0.2
  - python_abi=3.10
  - pytorch=2.0.0
  - pytorch-cuda=11.7
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0
  - pytz=2023.3.post1
  - pyyaml=6.0
  - pyzmq=25.1.0
  - re2=2022.04.01
  - readline=8.2
  - regex=2023.10.3
  - requests=2.31.0
  - responses=0.13.3
  - sacremoses=0.0.43
  - scikit-learn=1.0.1
  - scipy=1.10.1
  - setuptools=68.0.0
  - six=1.16.0
  - snappy=1.1.9
  - sqlite=3.41.2
  - stack_data=0.2.0
  - sympy=1.11.1
  - tbb=2021.8.0
  - threadpoolctl=2.2.0
  - tk=8.6.12
  - tokenizers=0.13.3
  - torchaudio=2.0.0
  - torchtriton=2.0.0
  - torchvision=0.15.0
  - tornado=6.2
  - tqdm=4.65.0
  - traitlets=5.7.1
  - transformers=4.29.2
  - types-pytz=2022.4.0.0
  - typing_extensions=4.7.1
  - tzdata=2023c
  - urllib3=1.26.16
  - utf8proc=2.6.1
  - wcwidth=0.2.5
  - wheel=0.38.4
  - x264=1!157.20191217
  - xformers=0.0.19
  - xxhash=0.8.0
  - xz=5.4.2
  - yaml=0.2.5
  - yarl=1.8.1
  - zeromq=4.3.4
  - zlib=1.2.13
  - zstd=1.5.5
  - pip:
    - absl-py==2.0.0
    - accelerate==0.24.1
    - aiostream==0.5.2
    - annotated-types==0.6.0
    - anyio==3.7.1
    - asgiref==3.7.2
    - backoff==2.2.1
    - bcrypt==4.1.2
    - bitsandbytes==0.42.0
    - build==1.0.3
    - cachetools==5.3.2
    - chroma-hnswlib==0.7.3
    - chromadb==0.4.22
    - coloredlogs==15.0.1
    - dataclasses-json==0.5.14
    - deprecated==1.2.14
    - distro==1.8.0
    - evaluate==0.4.0
    - exceptiongroup==1.1.3
    - fastapi==0.109.2
    - flatbuffers==23.5.26
    - google-auth==2.27.0
    - googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
    - greenlet==3.0.1
    - grpcio==1.60.1
    - h11==0.14.0
    - httpcore==1.0.1
    - httptools==0.6.1
    - httpx==0.25.1
    - humanfriendly==10.0
    - importlib-metadata==6.11.0
    - importlib-resources==6.1.1
    - jsonpatch==1.33
    - jsonpointer==2.4
    - kubernetes==29.0.0
    - langchain==0.0.150
    - langsmith==0.0.60
    - llama-index==0.8.64.post1
    - marshmallow==3.20.1
    - mmh3==4.1.0
    - monotonic==1.6
    - mypy-extensions==1.0.0
    - nest-asyncio==1.5.8
    - nltk==3.8.1
    - oauthlib==3.2.2
    - onnxruntime==1.17.0
    - openai==1.2.1
    - openapi-schema-pydantic==1.2.4
    - opentelemetry-api==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-proto==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-sdk==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-util-http==0.43b0
    - overrides==7.7.0
    - peft==0.3.0
    - posthog==3.4.0
    - protobuf==4.25.2
    - pulsar-client==3.4.0
    - pyasn1==0.5.1
    - pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
    - pydantic==1.10.13
    - pydantic-core==2.10.1
    - pypika==0.48.9
    - pyproject-hooks==1.0.0
    - python-dotenv==1.0.1
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
    - rouge-score==0.1.2
    - rsa==4.9
    - sentencepiece==0.1.96
    - sniffio==1.3.0
    - sqlalchemy==2.0.23
    - starlette==0.36.3
    - tenacity==8.2.3
    - tiktoken==0.5.1
    - tomli==2.0.1
    - trl==0.4.2.dev0
    - typer==0.9.0
    - typing-extensions==4.9.0
    - typing-inspect==0.9.0
    - uvicorn==0.27.0.post1
    - uvloop==0.19.0
    - watchfiles==0.21.0
    - websocket-client==1.7.0
    - websockets==12.0
    - wrapt==1.15.0
    - zipp==3.17.0
prefix: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/llm_022624
```